# Picasso is loading images again on tab switch

Tags: android, picasso

I have three tabs in `RecyclerView` which has `Picasso` for image loading along with `TextView`. When I switch between tabs, I see that image is loading again. Is my image not caching with Picasso?

I'm using a FragmentPagerAdapter. Below is the code where I'm switching fragments.

```
 public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                NewsFragment textFragment = new NewsFragment();
                return textFragment;
            case 1:
                FactsFragment imagesFragment = new FactsFragment();
                return imagesFragment;

            case 2:
                NewsstandFragment newsstandFragment = new NewsstandFragment();
                return newsstandFragment;
            case 3:
                SavedFragment savedFragment = new SavedFragment();
                return savedFragment;

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Share your code where you are switching tabs.

Comment: I am using recyclerview inside a nested scrollview. The reason for this is laggy vertical scroll. And that is causing this picasso reload on tabswitch. Is that weird or expected?

Comment: Please share your code where you are switching.